# rJava .jnew java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, r, rjava

I am new to 'rJava' and meet some troubles for hours.

```
library(rJava)
.jinit(classpath="C:\\Users\\XXX\\desktop\\example")
.jclassPath()
# [1] "C:\\Users\\XXX\\Documents\\R\\win-library\\3.5\\rJava\\java"          
# [2] "C:\\Users\\XXX\\desktop\\example" 
s=.jnew("java/lang/String", "Hello World")
.jcall(s, "I", "length")
# 11
.jcall('Exampletest', returnSig='I', method='test')
# 1
.jnew('Exampletest', 3)
# Error in .jnew("Exampletest", 3) : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: <init>
```

This is quite weired since I have successfully call the function 'test' but still fail to new the object.

The java code is here

```
public class Exampletest {

    static public int test() {
        return 1;
    }

    public Exampletest(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    private int x;
}
```

Any idea is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha, I have met this problem last year when I begin to use rJava. This problem is simply because in r, 3 is a numeric number but not an integer. So you should use `3L` instead of `3`。

BTW, if the arguments have the `long` type in java, `3L` is not working again. You should use `.jlong(3)` instead of `3L` again. The signature of the function is quite important in rJava!

Comment: Yes! Changing to 3L solve my problem. Can I ask one more question? I find that after I change my java code and recompile it with javac, the code in R seems to be the old version? Because the code result is not change

Comment: Well, this may because the jvm doesn't load the new .class file. Have you ever try to use `.jinit` again?

Comment: Try to use `.rs.restartR()` to restart the session, this can solve anything. Or you should go to check the document to see whether there is a function to reload the .class file.